Is there a way in R using writeData function to add dataframe to existing sheet where the row is empty
I am new to Stackoverflow. I wrote some R script and currently working on a script where I would like to use writeData function to add a dataframe to an existing excel sheet. I was able to tell R which row and column to add the data by telling row and column index number.
But is there any way to use writeData to add dataframe only to the rows that are blanks?
For example if I say that write date frame column 3:7 if certain row or cell is blank. Currently this what I am using:
library(openxlsx)
writeData(wb, sheet = "test", df_Report, start row=1, start col = 2)

It allows me to add data to existing sheet but I have to tell where to add the data. What I am looking a way to add data to sheet where the row or cell is blank.

What package is your writedata function from? openxlsx?

Yes I am using openxlsx

What you want to do is very dependent on the details.  It is difficult to help without being a lot more specific.

Assuming there is existing data in a sheet of a workbook, how about reading that sheet in first, then nrow(df) + 1 of that dataframe df should theoretically give you row number for a row that is blank.

I tried nrow but it's not working because the existing sheet has two columns date and data. In these case the date end in row 31 and data end in 17 by running this it select row 32 and add the data not row 17. Also what I am looking is that each time run the script it should increment the row after adding the data to empty cell

Basically what I am looking is that each time when is write data function it should increment start row by 1

Nevermind I figured it out by selecting the specific column and using nrow it work. Thanks for the help
